# Unresponsive Table Elements when Setting Table Height/Width

Tags: html, css

CSS setting a table height or width makes some table rows `<tr>` and table data `<td>` unclickable or unable to highlight or unresponsive.

```
<style>
.tbl-content{
position:absolute; 
height:; /* if you set a height table data or rows become non-responsive*/
width:; /* if you set a width table data or rows become non-responsive*/
overflow-x:auto;
margin-top: 0px;
}
th{
padding: 20px 15px;
text-align: left;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 12px;
color: #fff;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
th:first-child{
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 50px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
}
th:last-child{
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 50px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
}
tr:hover {
background-color: #464A52;  
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this answer was gotten from https://blog.lysender.com/2014/09/css-elements-covered-by-a-container-div-not-clickable/#comment-3400

I asked and answered this cause it took me a whole day to solve this issue and the solution was not on StackOverflow yet

CSS pointer-events

The CSS style pointer-events can be set to none so that it will not receive hover/clicks events, instead, the event will occur on anything behind it. However, there is no luck making it work on browsers IE 10 and below. See compatibility table.

CSS pointer-events by caniuse.com

Since the link is just partially covered at the bottom by the div, I decided to give pointer-events: none a try.

```
.some-horizontal-container {
pointer-events: none;
}
```

However, all child elements will receive no hover/clicks as well. To fix that, we need to turn pointer-events back specific to these elements.

```
.some-horizontal-container a.btn{
pointer-events: all;
}
```

The better way

There was a severe drawback when I disable the pointer events for the widget I am working on especially with touch events. I found a better way where it works for all scenarios.

Instead of disabling and enabling the pointer events, I used the visibility style instead.

```
visibility:hidden; for the div that overlays the clickable element under it, then visibility: visible; for the child elements of the overlay where it should be clickable.
```

These child elements do not cover anything under it and they are just small buttons.

That’s it!